# How to set value from payload to state Redux ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a problem with put value from action to state, maybe somebody can help me!

***How I can change searchFilter?? Thanks!***

I have action (all is good value come to this place 100%)

```
  console.log("SEARCH_FILTER_CHANGE", value);
  return {
    type: "SEARCH_FILTER_CHANGE",
    payload: value
  };
};
```

I write next code here in reducer

```
const INITAL_STATE = {
  films: [],
  searchFilter: "", // name or actors
  searchValue: "" // search value from input
};

export default (state = INITAL_STATE, { type, payload }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case "SEARCH_FILTER_CHANGE":
      return {
            // !!! MY PROBLEM IS ON THE NEXT LINE

        searchFilter: payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: what do you get, any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's check what a **reducer** doing! it returns new state with a action. so the object you return in reducer is **new State** . Ok so we should keep all current state and only change the special property that we want, it can be done with spread arguments.

```
case "SEARCH_FILTER_CHANGE":
return {
    ...state,
    searchFilter: payload
}
```

so we change old state to new state.

if you want to access to your state in the component just connect it to redux.

feel free to ask more questions in comment.

Answer (score 2):

Since one of the core tenets of Redux is to never mutate state. You should always check that you have returned a new copy of it. Hence, you should add the rest of it without overriding 
 it:

```
case "SEARCH_FILTER_CHANGE":
    return {
        ...state,
        searchFilter: payload
    };
```

By using the spread (...) operator, you can copy enumerable properties from one object to another in a more succinct way. And avoiding mutating or overriding your state.

Check this reference https://redux.js.org/recipes/using-object-spread-operator

Feel free to ask for more info In the comments